# User-defined temperature threshold in HP iLO4

Tags: hp-proliant, ilo

I would like to change the factory-defined temperature threshold in iLO4, specifically I want to set a numerical value for the two sensors that have a threshold of "N/A".

I have a DL380pG8 (with iLO4) that is monitored via Zenoss (a infrastructure monitoring tool).

One of the things monitored is the temperature - the server has 20+ temperature sensors, and all of them have what seems to be a factory-defined threshold beyond which the server might take action (auto shutdown for example)...except for 2 sensors that have a threshold of "N/A".

The issue I have is that my monitoring tool compares current temperature to the threshold, and gives an alert if the temp goes above the threshold.  Which is a problem for the two sensors because they constantly give out false alarms as a threshold of "N/A" is taken to be a temperature of zero degrees celcius. I would rather not just ignore those alarms, but set up the iLO to have some sort of value for threshold instead of "N/A".

How do I modify those factory-defined values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can't - the only solution was to force the monitoring software to accept a hard coded value when the threshold wasn't present in iLO4.

Answer (score 0):

Few options....

1. Ensure you are running the latest FW.  Temp thresholds can get updated or corrected in newer FW.
2. Go into bios setup and look for the thermal section.  There is an option there to ignore thresholds.  This setting can propogate into the IPMI instances exposed to your monitoring SW.